# Override third party module customerData class defined in di.xml arguments

Tags: magento2, third-party-module, preference, di.xml, customer-data

I have a third party module that has this class

```
app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/CustomerData/Popup.php
```

and that class is defined in the `frontend/di.xml` file like this

```
    <type name="Magento\Customer\CustomerData\SectionPoolInterface">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="sectionSourceMap" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="popup" xsi:type="string">Vendor\ModuleName\CustomerData\Popup</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
```

I am trying to override the class "app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/CustomerData/Popup.php" as it has some protected methods.
I tried to use preferences in myVendor `etc/di.xml` file like

```
<preference for="Vendor\ModuleName\CustomerData\Popup" type="MyVendor\VendorModuleNameExtend\Rewrite\Vendor\ModuleName\CustomerData\Popup"/>
```

But this is not working and on the storefront, I get errors on customerData.js.

Is there a way that I can override that third-party module `di.xml` or class and replace my own with `argument->item` of my own class?

Comment: for argument or add new dependency you can use virtual type and create new sub class

Comment: @Vikaskalal tnx, can you please add a document or a sample tutorial? I couldn't fine something useful.

Comment: Yoc can follow this tutorial to create virtual type may your requirement fulfilled. https://asolutions.co.in/virtual-type-in-magento-2/

Comment: tnx, I will check it.